# Check for duplicate characters in C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a program where you input 20 characters into an array. Each time you enter a new character, the program should check if that character is already in the array, if it is, print duplicate (but still add the duplicate to the array)

For example, if user types 'a', program should check if 'a' is inside the array.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char myAlpha[20];
    char input;

    cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
    for (int i= 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        for (int k = 0; k <= 20; k++) {
            if (myAlpha[k] == input)
                cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
        }
        myAlpha[i] = input;
    }

}
```

I just can't figure out how to make it work, I'm probably missing something stupid. The solution must use something like the code above, no fancy functions or anything.

EDIT: Fixed Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char myAlpha[20];
    char input;

    cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
    for (int i= 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if (myAlpha[k] == input)
                cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
        }
        myAlpha[i] = input;
    }
}
```

Only problem is that "duplicate" is printed a extra time for each duplication of a letter. For example, if 'a' is entered 3 times, on the 3rd time, "duplicate" is printed 2 times. And so on. But not a big deal.

Comment: In what way is your current code not working?

Comment: You never initialize `myAlpha` to anything, but you access its elements. That's undefined behavior. You need to assign something to the elements of `myAlpha` *before* accessing it

Comment: Changing it to k < i was the simplest way to fix the program. :) Thanks Michael and everyone else for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char myAlpha[20];
    char input;

    cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cin >> input;
        myAlpha[i] = input;
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if (myAlpha[k] == input)
                cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This algorithm will mark every character as duplicate, and it's because you moved the `myAlpha[i] = input;`. Change the inner loop to use the condition `k < i`, and that should fix this

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
char myAlpha[20];
```

The valid indices of that array are from 0 to 19.  However, this line:

```
for (int i= 0; i <= 20; i++) {
```

Already implies a bug.  Change it to this:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 20; i++) {
```

Do the same treatment for the inner for loop line: `for (int k = 0; k <= 20; k++) {`

But... you'll also need to keep track of how many characters have been inserted instead of looping up to `20` again.

So this is closer to what you want:

```
int main() {

    char myAlpha[20];
    char input;

    cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
    int inserted = 0;
    while (inserted < 20) {
        cin >> input;

        bool duplicate = false;

        for (int k = 0; k < inserted; k++) {
            if (myAlpha[k] == input) {
                cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
                duplicate = true;
                break; // no point in continuing to look for duplicates once the first one is found
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
             myAlpha[inserted] = input;
            inserted++;   
        }
    }

}
```

Even faster and you can avoid the inner for-loop:

```
int main() {

    bool duplicates[256] = {};
    char myAlpha[20] = {};
    char input;

    cout << "Enter a letter" << endl;
    int inserted = 0;
    while (inserted < 20) {
        cin >> input;

        bool duplicate = duplicates[(unsigned char)input];
        if (duplicate) {
            cout << "Duplicate" << endl;
        }
        else {
            myAlpha[inserted] = input;
            inserted++;
            duplicates[(unsigned char)input] = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not quite. The inner loop should not scan the entire array, only the elements that have already been filled in. So the loop test should be `k < i`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - I wasn't finished with my answer when you typed your comment. :)